# GridView Export To Excel From Chrome Not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am having Asp.net application. For Reporting, We are using GridView with Export to Excel. Same works on IE When same is done from Chrome Browser .aspx Page gets Downloaded.

Below is the Code for Exporting

```
    Dim Excelfilename As String = "OnlinePaymentTranRpt" + 
         Format(DateTime.Now, "ddMMyyyyhhmm")

      Response.Clear()
      Response.Buffer = True
      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" 
              + Excelfilename + ".xls")
      Response.Charset = ""

      'Me.EnableViewState = False
         Dim oStringWriter As System.IO.StringWriter = New 
             System.IO.StringWriter()
           Dim oHtmlTextWriter As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New 
             System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter)


           GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter)
            Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString())
              Response.End()
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: Thanks for Solutions. NPOI export to excel has worked for me.